# Why is my output showing as X?

Tags: verilog

I have written a Verilog file for memory error correcting that takes an n-bit input and using certain logic, it would output an n-bit output that would possess the corrected code. Here are my modules I am using.

```
module Majority3(input wire [2:0] S, output wire O);

    assign O = S[0]&S[1]&S[2] | S[0]&S[1]&~S[2] | S[0]&~S[1]&S[2] | ~S[0]&S[1]&S[2];

endmodule

module OLS(input wire [15:0] Data, output wire [15:0] Errors);

    wire [1:0] xorOut0;
    wire [1:0] xorCheck0;
    assign xorCheck0[0] = Data[0] ^ Data[1] ^ Data[2] ^ Data[3];
    assign xorCheck0[1] = Data[0] ^ Data[4] ^ Data[5] ^ Data[6] ^ Data[7];
    assign xorOut0[0] = Data[1] ^ Data[2] ^ Data[3] ^ xorCheck0[0];
    assign xorOut0[1] = Data[4] ^ Data[5] ^ Data[6] ^ Data[7] ^ xorCheck0[1];
    Majority3 m0 (.S({xorOut0[0], xorOut0[1]}), .O(Errors[0]));
    
    wire [1:0] xorOut1;
    wire [1:0] xorCheck1;
    assign xorCheck1[0] = Data[0] ^ Data[1] ^ Data[2] ^ Data[3];
    assign xorCheck1[1] = Data[1] ^ Data[4] ^ Data[8] ^ Data[9] ^ Data[10] ^ Data[11];
    assign xorOut1[0] = Data[0] ^ Data[2] ^ Data[3] ^ xorCheck1[0];
    assign xorOut1[1] = Data[4] ^ Data[8] ^ Data[9] ^ Data[10] ^ Data[11] ^ xorCheck1[1];
    Majority3 m1 (.S({xorOut1[0], xorOut1[1]}), .O(Errors[1]));

    //....

    wire [1:0] xorOut15;
    wire [1:0] xorCheck15;
    assign xorCheck15[0] = Data[2] ^ Data[5] ^ Data[8] ^ Data[12] ^ Data[13] ^ Data[14] ^ Data[15];
    assign xorCheck15[1] = Data[15];
    assign xorOut15[0] = Data[2] ^ Data[5] ^ Data[8] ^ Data[12] ^ Data[13] ^ Data[14] ^ xorCheck15[0];
    assign xorOut15[1] = xorCheck15[1];
    Majority3 m15 (.S({xorOut15[0], xorOut15[1]}), .O(Errors[15]));


endmodule
```

There are n "chunks" of that code based on how many bits are in the input, in this case there are 16 that look somewhat similar with different combinations of xor'd bits. I am not including them all for the sake of space, but if needed I can edit my question to include the full code.

And here is my testbench:

```
module testbench();

//inputs
reg [15:0] Data = 0;
//outputs
wire [15:0] Errors = 0;

OLS uut (
    .Data (Data),
    .Errors (Errors)
);

integer k = 0;

initial
begin
    #100;
end
initial
begin
    Data = 0;
    
    for(k = 0; k<16; k=k+1) begin
        Data[k] = 1;
        if(k>0) begin
            Data[k-1] = 0;
        end
        #5;
    end

    #5 $finish;
end

initial
    begin
        $dumpfile("dump.vcd");
        $dumpvars;
    end
    
endmodule
```

So the problem I am having is regarding my simulation. The 'Error' output shows an 'X' wherever there is a bit being turned to 1 in my testbench, however I expect the output to be 0 at all times for this first testbench iteration because using a majority voter of 3 inputs, at most only 1 of those inputs would be a 1 while the other 2 are 0, hence the assurance of the output being 0 at all times. I am failing to see where I went wrong that is causing the 'X' to be present.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why did you post this question twice? https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/630682/why-is-my-output-showing-as-x

Comment: @TonyM: That other question is different from this one.  The answer for this question is uniquely different from the answer on the other question.  The X here was caused by undriven signals, whereas the X in the other question was caused by multiple drivers of a signal.

Comment: @toolic, looking at them, the question text is identical in both. If the OP has posted different firmware in each, which I have not scrutinised, they are opening themselves up to duplicate question close votes and that's what they got.

Comment: @TonyM: But, the 2nd question is not a duplicate, and it should be re-opened.  There are many causes of X in Verilog, and these 2 questions show 2 of the different reasons.

Comment: @TonyM: I updated [the other question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/630685/why-is-my-output-showing-x-despite-all-inputs-driven-in-my-simulation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simulator I am using generates compile warnings like:

```
    Majority3 m0 (.S({xorOut0[0], xorOut0[1]}), .O(Errors[0]));
                     |
xmelab: *W,CUVMPW : port sizes differ in port connection(2/3) for the instance(testbench.uut) .
```

`S` is a 3-bit input port of the `Majority3` module, but you are only driving 2 bits.  The MSB (`S[2]`) is undriven, and it results in the `O` output being unknown.

You need to drive all bits of the input port with known values to avoid the X.

---

If your simulator does not generate warnings, you can try your code on other simulators on edaplayground.

Comment: @Spice: make sure you do not change the code to invalidate my answer.  It might be better to post a  new question if you do.